# Need some help with basic HTML select and ie

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I reproduce the error in this jsfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge/KftG6/5/

Here is my HTML:

```
    <table id="infoMedicament" style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
        <td style="width:50%">Value 1<br />
        <select id="produit1" class="produit">
            <option value="d02237726" >test1</option>
            <option value="d02326701" >test2</option>
            <option value="d02041421" >test3</option>
            <option value="d02240240" >test4</option>
            <option value="d00821772" >test5</option>
            <option value="d02225190" >test6</option>
            <option value="new">add</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td style="width:50%; vertical-align:top;">Search<br />
            <input type="text" id="rechercheNouveauProduitTab2" style="width:250px;" />
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

It works fine in Chrome, but IE tries to open a popup.

Any idea ?

Here is a screen shot of the behavior I have. I have the popup blocker that appears right after I click on the `<select>`

[image]

Comment: I think you're missing some code in your example.

Comment: try the jsfiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge/KftG6/5/

Comment: I did - unless I'm missing something there's just a dropdown and a text box. No javascript or events.

Comment: Exactly my point. Why is IE8 trying to open a popup?

Comment: sorry - wasn't clear from your post. I opened it in IE 9 and set browser mode to IE 8 - didn't see a pop up. Could you have something cached locally? Nothing about that code should pop anything up.

Comment: will turn on PC with IE8 to check this out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your codes issue, jsfiddle.net coused it first two times for me :)

Comment: You were right !! My Internet Explorer installation has been corrupted. After reinstalling IE everything works fine. CAUTION: Do not install IE7 Stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

You have incomplete code, try surrounding your form inputs with a  tag, with some action.

Comment: Sorry what you see is what you've got. There is nothing else in the html file.